# Slf4j logger log fields from parent class

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j, lombok

I have following code:

```
@Slf4j
public class Main {

@Data
public static class AClass {
    private String title;
}

@Data
public static class BClass extends AClass {
    private Integer amount;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BClass bClass = new BClass();
    bClass.setAmount(12);
    bClass.setTitle("title");

    log.info("{}", bClass);
}
}
```

In logs I can see only fields from BClass and not AClass :

> 17:52:28.151 [main] INFO Main - Main.BClass(amount=12)

But I want to see all BClass fields including ones that are in parent class(title field). How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

That's normal - what you're looking at (specifically, the `Main.BClass(amount=12)` part in your log) is the output of the `toString()` method of `BClass`. The `@Data` annotation is making a toString implementation for you. However, lombok intentionally does not include superclass information normally. You should be seeing a warning on your `@Data` annotation that explains this. One way to solve that problem is to add `@ToString(callSuper = true)` next to your `@Data` annotation.

This isn't about SLF4J or any logging framework - it's about what is and isn't in the generated `toString()` implementation.